# Can you add a scrollTop method to the HTML body?

Tags: jquery, html

So I've checked out a few tutorials for making stuff happen when you scroll to a certain point. Everyone seems to use a div window with some text inside of it.

I tried to do the same thing, but with the whole body element, so when the user scrolls to a certain element, that element becomes bigger, or something like that.

For the start I tried to make an h1 element show what position the vertical scroll is at using scrollTop. But nothing seems to happen.

jQuery

```
<script>
$(document).ready(function (){
        $("body").scroll(function (){
            var scrollPosition = $this.scrollTop();
            $("#info").text(scrollPosition);
        });
    });
</script>
```

HTML

```
<body>

<div class="contaienr-fluid">
    <h1 id="info"></h1>
</div>
<div class="container-fluid">
    <h1>asd<br />
    asd <br />
    asd <br />
    asd <br />
    asd <br />
    asd <br />
    asd <br />
    asd <br />
    asd <br />
    asd <br />
    asd <br />
    asd <br />
    asd <br />
    asd <br />
    asd <br />
    asd <br />
    asd <br />
    asd <br />
    </h1> <!-- I know, incredibly stupid way to create space on the page-->
</div>
</body>
```

Comment: You scroll to top directly when the page is loaded. The fact is you are already on top of the page.

Comment: [jsFiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/ka5ppmv4/2/) the console "***`Uncaught ReferenceError: $this is not defined`***" so change it to `$(this).scrollTop();` instead of `$this.scrollTop();`,  the console is your friend

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The origin of the scroll event and positioning is from the `window` object, so you can use it.

```
<script>
    $(document).ready(function (){
        $(window).scroll(function (){
            var scrollPosition = $this.scrollTop();
            $("#info").text(scrollPosition);
        });
    });
</script>
```

This requires the window to scroll and wont work if you have fullsized divs that are only scrolled inside, like it is done in webapps.